# Firewall: How to Allow Application to Access Database at Database Server

Tags: security, mysql, windows-xp, firewall

I have 2 machines, one is used as to host application ( Application Server), another is used to host database ( database server). Both are windows XP.

Now as the App Server needs to access the database server, I need to set the firewall to allow for app server db access the database (mysql), how to configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only access the application server needs to the database server is MySQL, then you just need to add a port exception to the Windows Firewall on the database server for the application server.

- In the Windows Firewall control panel applet, on the "Exceptions" tab, click "Add Port".
- Enter "MySQL" (or anything you want... "Bob", "Ice Cream", etc) as the "Name", and "3306" as the "Port Number".
- Click the "Change Scope..." button.
- In the "Change Scope" dialog, click the "Custom" radio button. Enter the IP address of the database server.
- "OK" your way back out.
- From the application server computer, test connectivity to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql defaults to listen on port 3306.  So you would need to allow your app server access to port 3306 on your database server.

Check out [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html) for more documentation.

Josh